# How to add default folder in document library Json Schema - Team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json, team-sites, site-design

I would like to add functionality to my script to add a default "Archive" folder to Document library. It would be good to add in the upper part of the screen an explanation what files should be there.

Currently the structure looks like this:

General files (Document library)
in the middle the folder "Archive".

Here my script, which creates document library:

```
  {
        "verb": "createSPList",
        "listName": "General files",
        "templateType": 101
    },
    {
        "verb": "addNavLink",
        "url": "/General%20files/Forms/AllItems.aspx",
        "displayName": "Client documents",
        "isWebRelative": true
    }
```

I don't see any parameter here that specifies creating an empty folder in document library.

[Create a new SharePoint list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema#create-a-new-sharepoint-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating folders inside document library using Site design script is **not possible**.

However, you can trigger a flow using site design script which will create default folders inside document library.

More information on triggering flow at: [Trigger a flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema#trigger-a-flow)

**Similar issue on GitHub**: [Is there JSON code to create Folders in a document library?](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4385)

**Additional Reference**: [MS Flow – Create new folder action](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/MS-Flow-Create-new-folder-action/ba-p/355632)

Comment: Unfortunately this will work for one particular site.... If we have many sites and they have different url's then creating folders will not work :/